# my select PHP function does not work properly

Tags: php, mysql, web-services

i create a webservice and i call a function to confirm user, but every time i call the function, i receive "registration confirmed" message even if i send the wrong vercode, here is my function implementation, consider ckey is constant and not changable and vercode is changable for every user, i think the problem is about mysql instructions.

```
// RPC method 2 (confirm user)
 function confuser($ckey, $vercode) {
    $db = mysql_connect("localhost","root");
     if(!$db){
      return 'Error: cannot open the connection';
      exit;
    }

     mysql_select_db('user_info');
      $query = "select * from personal where vercode='".$vercode."' and ckey='".$ckey."' ";
        $result = mysql_query($query, $db);
         if($result){
             return 'registration confirmed';
             } 
             else{
                 return 'wrong verification , send it again!';
             }
 }
```

Comment: use `mysql_num_rows` to see if there is rows or not http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mysql_query()` will return a result handle on ANY successful query. That includes queries that returned ZERO rows. A zero-row result is still a valid result, it just happens to have nothing in it. You will NOT get a "false" return on zero-row queries.

You need to check the number of rows found, e.g.

```
$result = mysql_query(...);
if (!$result) {
   die(mysql_error()); // in case something did blow up
}
if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 0) {
    ... wrong verification ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use something like this:

```
if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0){
    return 'registration confirmed';
} 
else{
    return 'wrong verification , send it again!';
}
```

Comment: You will want to use @vivek sharma's answer. $result will always return true if it successfully executed. Counting the amount of rows returned is the best way to check if the exists or not with the given information.

Answer (score 0):

```
mysql_select_db('user_info') or die(mysql_error());
$query = "select * from personal where vercode='$vercode' and ckey='$ckey'";
$result = mysql_query($query, $db) or die(mysql_error());
if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0)
    return 'registration confirmed';      
return 'wrong verification , send it again!';
```

Please note that you need to secure your variables $vercode and $ckey. mysql_real_escape_string() was used to be the escape method, but now mysql_real_escape_string(), and most of the functions you used will be deprecated starting php 5.5.0. Alternatively you can use [PDO prepared statements](https://www.php.net//manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php)